# AV Player view controller not closing

Tags: swift, xcode, avplayerviewcontroller, ios12

I updated to iOS 12 and the AV Player VC close button don't work anymore. The screen never dismissed, it pause the video instead. This actions was working just fine on previous iOS versions.

Is there any particular reason for this?

EDIT: Added code

```
    guard let movieURL = URL(string: urlStr) else { return }
    moviePlayer = AVPlayer(url: movieURL)
    self.moviePLayerViewController.player = moviePlayer
    moviePLayerViewController.view.frame = vwMainContainer.bounds

    moviePLayerViewController.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
    moviePLayerViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext


    present(moviePLayerViewController, animated: true) {
        self.moviePlayer?.play()
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, i made the change.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't showed any Code there

Just try the following method It just work perfectly fine for me

```
//MARK: Play Video At Index Path
func playVideoWith(_ videoURL: URL) {
    let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL)
    let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
    playerViewController.player = player
    playerViewController.view.frame = self.view.frame
    self.present(playerViewController, animated: true) {
        playerViewController.player?.play()
    }
}
```

**Note - Please show code So, we can see where the mistake is else just try above code once and let me know did it helped ?**

Comment: I am sorry to post no code, I was doing the same as your example but with a modal presentation style to that view, I just remove it and it worked again. I don't remember why i added it in the first place, but it wasn't causing troubles before.

Comment: No issues, You can post your own Answer and accept that to close this thread or just accept my answer if this helped you In any case to close this thread. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It is resolved now, I just removed the modal presentation style and worked again. I am not sure why this was a problem, if anyone know pleas answer.

```
guard let movieURL = URL(string: urlStr) else { return }
    moviePlayer = AVPlayer(url: movieURL)
    self.moviePLayerViewController.player = moviePlayer
    moviePLayerViewController.view.frame = vwMainContainer.bounds
    present(moviePLayerViewController, animated: true) {
        self.moviePlayer?.play()
    }
```